# Characters from embedded Google fonts not showing up in Firefox 4 and IE9

Tags: css, font-face, google-webfonts

Posting here is a bit of a long shot (I can´t reach the developer), but I´m having a problem with a font that I´m embedding using Google web fonts.

The font I´m embedding is Molengo and the problem I have is that the capital `Z` does not show up in Firefox 4 nor in IE 9. It does show in Chrome 10.

In Firefox 4 the character occupies space and in IE9 it is totally collapsed.

I can reproduce the problem not only on my test site, but also on the official [Google web fonts page](http://www.google.com/webfonts/family?family=Molengo&subset=latin#set). At least on my computer the box of the `Z` does not show the character in Fx4 and IE9 and I don´t have another machine at hand to test on.

Clicking around on Google web fonts, I found the problem at other places as well, like the `%` character of the [Candal font family](http://www.google.com/webfonts/family?family=Candal&subset=latin#set).

So is my computer just going crazy or is there a problem with random characters from Google web fonts in Fx4 and IE9? And if it is the latter, is there a solution for this problem?

**Edit:** I just tried generating some `Z`'s using Molengo on [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Molengo), but they only seem to generate images instead of actual texts.

Comment: You're not alone, I'm seeing the same issue.

Comment: @BoltClock That´s too bad, the developers web-site does not open so I was kind of hoping it was just me...

Comment: I see the Z in FF4 but not in IE 9. Both Win 7 64 Bit.

Comment: @toscho Strange, I´m using Win 7 64bit as well.

Comment: Firefox, Chrome Win 7 32bit show up fine

Comment: Oh, this question belongs on WebDevelopers as it's not programming related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded the same font from [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Molengo), uploaded it to my own server and included all types like in the demo page and now it shows the `Z` both in Firefox 4 and IE9.

And all other characters as far as I can tell :-)

Very weird, the problem seems to be related to Google web fonts only.