# WebFont loaded from Google Font API looks awful in Firefox 3.6 on Windows only

Tags: css, font-face, firefox3.6, google-webfonts

For a site we're developing we've been using [Lato](http://www.google.com/webfonts/family?family=Lato&subset=latin) from Google's WebFonts API.  It works perfectly in every browser (even IE), except for one very important case: Firefox 3.6 on Windows XP (haven't tested in Win 7 yet).  The font loads and is displayed, but the characters look awful, like antialiasing completely malfunctioned.

[image: This is what the text looks like in FF3.6]

My googling has found hits about problems with webfonts in FF4 due to a bug in the browser, but I can't find anything about 3.6.  Is there something we can do to fix this?

Comment: It's possible to apply a bold style to an already bold font, which is failsville.  You'll also want ClearType enabled, if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason Google's font looks like that has to do with a setting in the font's GASP table. This table toggles 'grayscale' and 'gridfitting' for ranges of sizes. I looked at the font Google is sending to your site and for sizes 0-13 grayscale is turned on. 14-18 is set for gridfitting, which results in black and white rendering. Then 19+ is set for both grayscale and gridfitting. I bet if you changed the size of the text to 13px, it would suddenly turn antialiased.

As for Font Squirrel fonts, we set the GASP table to render grayscale+gridfitting for all sizes above 4px.

Comment: I switched to the Font Squirrel version and, after tweaking the stylesheet a bit, it works perfectly.  Thank you for the in-depth explanation.

Comment: Helped me out as well! I was having trouble with Google served Lato Light -- on any Windows browser, it looked terrible (OS X was fine). Loading the font squirrel ttf's from my server solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a difference between Google webfonts and the same font downloaded from [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/), see this (unrelated...) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426848/characters-from-embedded-google-fonts-not-showing-up-in-firefox-4-and-ie9).

So I would try and use the version they have at Font Squirrel to see if that solves the problem.