# the letters "ff" in "staff" are not displayed in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am observing a weird behavior in Firefox. I have a sub-nav menu item labelled 'Faculty and Staff'. Somehow Firefox(latest-always updated) is eating up the 'ff' in staff. The html source looks fine(even in firebug). The menu-item displays correctly in chrome though.
Do we have any idea about this issue? or should i log a bug with firefox?

Screenshot:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/bf945.png

Comment: Can we see your HTML and CSS? It may very well be the lowercase f simply being broken in your font file somehow, causing Firefox to choke, while Firefox is known to handle the Museo font perfectly.

Comment: How have you tried debugging it? Exactly: give us code instead of only screenshot!

Comment: I have had FF do some weird things in the past. Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: 1+ for screenshot. But post the code too!

Comment: I'd be suspicious that perhaps your font doesn't provide an [useful] ff-ligature? Does the same happen with (for example) fi, fl, ffi, ffl?

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much a good indicator to also check if there's any `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` going on. Just one of the clues to help narrow it down.

Comment: I've had a similar problem with the **Z** of a font using Google Fonts. That problem still persists with Firefox 8, I just checked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426848/characters-from-embedded-google-fonts-not-showing-up-in-firefox-4-and-ie9

Comment: Look at all the wild stabs in the dark as a symptom of the lack of markup to view.

Comment: Guess this is the HTML: http://www.aast.umd.edu/faculty.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yahoooo!
Currently solved by using:
**-moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=0";**

So this confirms that Firefox was in fact trying to treat that as a ligature.

Thank you all for helping me look in the right direction. Wouldn't have been possible with you guys. I <3 stackoverflow and the community :).

Comment: It only worked for me when I used the apostrophes according to the mozilla documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-feature-settings like this: h1 { -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga" 0; }

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure it really is two f's?

My guess is that your authoring application transformed the ff into the 'ff' ligature, which your specific font does not have a glyph for.

See here:

ff vs. ﬀ

You could test this, by going into your source and trying to select only 1 of the two f's. If you can only select them both at the same time, it's a single character and thus the ligature.

Comment: Not having a glyph for the ligature wouldn't be a problem per se; the browser would detect that and fall back to not using a ligature.  The problems come with fonts that do have a glyph and paint it blank....

Comment: Thank you all. @Evert: I tried looking at the source from the browser(view source), and i was able to select one 'f' at a time. So this seems like maybe its not considered a ligature, or the 'veiw source' is not able to show it as ligature, and the rendering happens separately.

Comment: @Boris: After i read your comment, i thought the font file might be damaged or have blanks for the ligature(if it is treated as a ligature), but the 'ff' displays correctly in chrome. So now I am left with two cases: 1. maybe its only firefox that is treating it as ligature and is not able to find the required one, eventually marking it as blank, 2. the ligature is infact marked as blank.      But in either case, shouldn't firefox make some additional checks like if ligature symbol not found then display the chars 'as is'?

Comment: @BoltClock: i tried adding text-rendering:optimizedSpeed, but it did not had any effects.

Comment: @rajankz Chrome doesn't do ligatures, last I checked.  Certainly not with default settings.  Again, what I suspect is happening here is that the font is claiming to have a glyph for the ligature; it just happens to not have any paths in the glyph... which is a perfectly valid thing for a font to do as far as it goes.